# Django form is_valid always false

Tags: django, django-forms

In my django application the form never returns true even if I add the same data as in the admin application. My model.py looks like:

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import ImageField, signals
from django.dispatch import dispatcher
from django.forms import ModelForm

# Create your models here.
class Image(models.Model):
    emailAddress = models.EmailField(max_length=75)
    image = ImageField(upload_to='photos')
    caption = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class UploadForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Image
```

My views.py looks like:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from competition.models import Image, UploadForm

# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    images = Image.objects.all().order_by('emailAddress')
    return render_to_response('images/index.html', {'images': images})

def uploadImage(request):
    if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...
        form = UploadForm(request.POST) # A form bound to the POST data
        if form.is_valid(): # All validation rules pass
            emailAddress = form.cleaned_data['emailAddress']
            image = form.cleaned_data['image']
            caption = form.cleaned_data['caption']
            i = Image(emailAddress=emailAddress, image = image, caption = caption)
            i.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('../image/')
        else:
            return render_to_response('images/upload.html', {'form': form})
    else:
        form = UploadForm() # An unbound form
        return render_to_response('images/upload.html', {'form': form})
```

My template looks like:

```
<html>
<body>
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/image/uploadImage" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I can get it work correctly if I use the admin application but need a generic form and this does't work as it keeps asking for a either the email address or image (the error appears above the image field). So why might my form not be valid?

Comment: @Cat Plus Plus, I've added the CSRF token, and the error is still happening. Why would this have made a difference? I thought the idea of is_valid was to check the data for validity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to instantiate your form with request.FILES as well as request.POST.

As an aside, you can save the model form instead of creating the Image by hand in the view.

Comment: This isn't documented very well. Yeah I had tried that but ofc it wasn't working, so I will change it now.

Comment: The documentation looks pretty clear to me. Please remember, Django is an open source project. Opening a ticket with a suggestion how to improve the documentation is more constructive than criticising it in stack overflow comments.

Answer (score 4):

You have a required image but you aren't binding the file data to the form.

```
form = UploadForm(request.POST)
```

should be

```
form = UploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
```

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/forms/api/#binding-uploaded-files

Answer (score 0):

**FileField** and **ImageField** fields have two places need to notice:

1. Require `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in form element.

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="/foo/">
```

2. Require `request.FILES` for form constructor.

```
form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
```

Please refer:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/file-uploads/
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/api/#binding-uploaded-files